# Как в Yii2 убрать название контроллера модуля из URL?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Как убрать название контроллера из URL, когда при запросе вызывается модуль?

**Имеем**

> [http://yii.local/Модуль/Контроллер/Действие](http://yii.local/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5)

**Нужно**

> [http://yii.local/Модуль/Действие](http://yii.local/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В настройках компонента используйте следующие правила:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'showScriptName' => false,   // Disable index.php
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,   // Disable r= routes
    'rules' => [
        '<module:(my-module-name)>/<action:(my-action-name)>' => '<module>/my-controller-name/<action>',
    ]
],
```

Подробнее читайте в документации, в разделе [правил роутинга](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/runtime-routing.md#url-rules-)

Comment: Это в `/config/web.php`? Я чего спрашиваю, просто я тоже так сделал, но что-то мне подсказывает, что это как-то нужно делать внутри модуля — ведь на то он и модуль.

Comment: @RomanGrinyov Вы всё правильно сделали. Модуль это просто модуль приложения, которое и выполняет роутинг запросов. Компонент `urlManager` можно и к модулю прикрепить, но точка входа это само приложение.

Comment: `Компонент urlManager можно и к модулю прикрепить` — это в классе модуля сконфигурировать его с помощью `Yii::configure()` как описано [здесь](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-modules.html#module-classes); где в файле `config.php` сделать [так](https://repl.it/Co3p)? Но тогда правила, которые мы определяем в этой конфигурации, не работают; ... это из-за того, что точка входа есть само приложение? Извините, если глупый вопрос, просто я не до конца понимаю workflow Yii2?

Comment: Кстати, был бы благодарен за информации по workflow Yii2 — я конечно потихоньку пытаюсь сам, смотря исходники, его понять, но инфа не помешала бы.

Comment: @RomanGrinyov все правильно вы понимаете :) http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-overview.html - Я могу только этот материал посоветовать. Пробовать и смотреть исходники это один из лучших способов!

Comment: Да, доки я шуршу + эта схема у меня на стенке перед глазами висит и другие тоже. Просто ... как бы так вроде всё понятно, но вот у меня желание представлять как это на программном уровне всё повязано, конечно не до строчки кода а в общем. Я потиху изучаю внутренности, но перед этим ничего не нагуглил аля: 1) входной скрипт — здесь мы делаем то-то (в доках есть, я знаю :)); 2) когда мы создаём экземпляр приложения `yii\web\Application` то мы вызываем конструктор `yii\base\Application`, так как в `yii\web\Application` он не переопределялся;

Comment: 3) в этом конструкторе мы назначаем в качестве значения свойства `Yii::$app` экземпляр `yii\web\Application`, то есть `$this` (класс `Yii` мы загрузили ранее, во входном скрипте; в файле этого класса регистрируется автозагрузчик `Yii` ...); 4) ... и т.д. и т.п., при этом чтобы пояснялось зачем мы это делаем :) . Конечно, бональные вещи можно опустить (хотя можно и не опускать). В общем я про такую документацию :) . По мне, так очень полезна бы была — закрыла бы многие возникающие вопросы при изучении (особенно у тех, для кого Yii — первый фрейморк).

Comment: @RomanGrinyov доки подобного уровня могут быть только в тестах, или в вашей голове после анализа :) Если вы анализируете код фреймворка то тут только анализ, документация она с точки зрения использования составлена.

Comment: `могут быть только в тестах` — что вы имеете в виду (не понял про какие тесты идёт речь)?.. А, кстати, сегодня в доках нарыл (хотя и так пришло в голову так сделать): [Adding Rules Dynamically](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#adding-rules). Вот только не знаю пока в каких ситуациях это предпочитается делать, а в каких нет ...

Comment: @RomanGrinyov самая лучшая низкоуровневая документация системы это юнит-тесты. Читая их можно много интересного узнать о системе :)

Comment: Я так и подумал (примерно :D), просто пока не дошёл до этого ... и так за последних 2 месяца мой мозг на грани взрыва от всего нового, интересно и полезного :) . Спасибо за ответы.